# Yii2 table not getting inserted with new record

Tags: insert, yii2, save

I'm trying to insert new data in my audit_trial table upon successful update of another table but it is not working. There is no relation between the two said table. Below is the sample code.

```
 if ($flag) {
    $transaction->commit();

    $audit = new AuditTrial();
    $audit->table_name = 'dep_customer';
    $audit->modified_by = 'tom';
    $audit->operation = 'update';
    $audit->save();

    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->customer_id]);
 }
```

I was hoping it should work as it is default way to create new record in yii2 but i'm not getting success. Am i missing something here? I'm still a amateur in Yii2. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not checking errors after `$audit->save()`? Your code isn't seems buggy.

Comment: @ZhukovRA I just did what you said. Just a simple if statement -  'if (audit->save()) echo "success"; ' and I'm not getting the message.

Comment: Ok! I got it. It's my mistake. The column 'modified_by' data type is 'int' and not 'varchar'. Now, it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use !$model->save for determining the data is inserted or not.

```
   $audit = new AuditTrial();
   $audit->table_name = 'dep_customer';
   $audit->modified_by = 'tom';
   $audit->operation = 'update';
   if($audit->save())return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->customer_id]);
   else {
      print_r($audit->getErrors());
      die();
   }
```